# How to add OU into LDAP using JNDI

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I would like to add a new `OU` into LDAP from JNDI. My LDAP server is setup from OpenDS.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String INITCTX = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    String MY_HOST = "ldap://localhost:1389";
    String MGR_DN = "cn=Directory Manager";
    String MGR_PW = "password";
    String MY_SEARCHBASE = "dc=QuizPortal";

    try
    {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITCTX);

        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, MY_HOST);

        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, MGR_DN);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, MGR_PW);

        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

        Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes(true); // case-ignore
        Attribute objclass = new BasicAttribute("objectclass");
        objclass.add("top");
        objclass.add("organizationalUnit");
        attrs.put(objclass);

        ctx.createSubcontext("ou=NewOu", attrs);
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - The provided entry ou=NewOu cannot be added because it does not have a parent and is not defined as one of the suffixes within the Directory Server]; remaining name 'ou=NewOu'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3066)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2987)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2794)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_createSubcontext(LdapCtx.java:788)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_createSubcontext(ComponentDirContext.java:319)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:248)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:236)
        at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.createSubcontext(InitialDirContext.java:178)
        at JUNDIAdd2.main(JUNDIAdd2.java:43)
```

Addition info: I have `o=IT, dc=QuizPortal` where I want to add in the new `OU`.

Could anyone guide me around this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
ctx.bind("ou=NewOu,o=IT", null, attrs);
```

You may need to set the ou attribute before:

```
attrs.put("ou", "NewOu");
```

Comment: Hey THANKS.. that works like a charm. 

For the benefit of others, with perry's answer and i have edited MY_HOST =  "ldap://localhost:1389/dc=QuizPortal", i am able to add the newOu under o=IT...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
ctx.createSubcontext("ou=NewOu,dc=QuizPortal,o=IT", attrs);
```

or this:

```
ctx.createSubcontext("ou=NewOu,dc=QuizPortal", attrs);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi there, I have tried these 2 methods but still having the error. 

I manage to add the newOu by changing MY_HOST = "ldap://localhost:1389"; to MY_HOST = "ldap://localhost:1389/dc=QuizPortal"; But it add the newOu under QuizPortal which is not what i wanted. I wanted to add newOu into IT